# Line of OCaml produces mysterious error

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

When I execute the code

```
let (a,p) = (2+2, Printf.printf) in p "abc"; p "%d" 3 ;;
```

I expect to see the output `abc3`, but get instead

```
File "f.ml", line 1, characters 46-47:
Error: This function has type (unit, out_channel, unit) format -> unit
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

The fun part is that if I change `2+2` to `2`, it runs.

Why does the code produce an error as is, but not with `+2` removed?

Comment: I am also interested in the answer, this is prima facie odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of OCaml's special typing trick for `printf` and value polymorphism.

As you may probably know, `Printf.printf` does not take `string` but data type `format`.  OCaml type checker has a special rule for typing of string literals for `printf`: if it is typed as `format` if the context requests:

```
# "%d";;
- : string = "%d"
# ("%d" : _format);;
- : (int -> 'a, 'b, 'a) format = ...
```

OCaml type system has another trick called value polymorphism (more precisely, it is relaxed value polymorphism).  Its purpose is to type expressions with side effects correctly.  I do not explain its details but it restricts polymorphism: some forms of expressions called "expansive" cannot have polymorphic types:

```
# fun x -> x;;
- : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
# (fun x -> x) (fun x -> x)
- : '_a -> '_a = <fun>
```

In the above, `(fun x -> x) (fun x -> x)` has no polymorphic type, while the identity function `fun x -> x` has.  This is due to the shape of the expression of `(fun x -> x) (fun x -> x)`: it is "expansive".  The strange type variable `'_a` is monomorphic type variable: it can be instantiated to some type only once. On the other hand, polymorphic variables like `'a` can be instantiated to a different type for each use of the vlaue.

Let's go back to your code:

```
# let (a, p) = (2, Printf.printf);;
val a : int
val p : ('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a
```

Here, `p` has a polymorphic type `('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a`. `'a` can be instantiated to more than one types therefore `p "abc"; p "%d" 3` is typable: the polymorphic type can be instantiated to `(unit, out_channel, unit) format -> unit` for the first use of `p`, and `(int -> unit, out_channel, unit) format -> int -> unit` for the second use of `p`.

Once you change the constant `2` to `2+2`, which is expansive, the entire expression becomes expansive too, and the typing changes:

```
# let (a, p) = (2+2, Printf.printf);;
val a : int
val p : ('_a, out_channel, unit) format -> '_a
```

Here, `p` has no longer polymorphic variables `'a` but monomorphic `'_a`.  This monomorphic variable is unified (instantiated) to `unit` at the first use of `p`, and as a result `p`'s type becomes `(unit, out_channel, unit) format -> unit`.  It can take only 1 argument therefore the typing of the second use of `p` with 2 arguments fails.

One easy way to avoid this situation is to split your definition into two:

```
let a = 2 + 2 in
let p = Printf.printf in
p "abc"; p "%d" 3
```